# Jquery not outputting an array into HTML

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Alright so I am trying to output simple JSON array in ajax but no matter what I do the HTML wont appear on the page at all...

```
$("#menu_zalbe").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url:"assets/core/handlers/reportHandler.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{function:"getAll"},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#content_split").html("<div class='content_Reports><p>Reporter<br/>"+data[i]['reporter']+"</p><br/></div>'");
            }
        },
        error:function(data) {
            console.log(data);  
        }

    });

});
```

I did console.log to check if there is an error or if it passing wrong data but everything is absolutely correct, there doesnt seem to be any problems but the HTML wont pop up on the page itself

Comment: Are you sure your data is not empty or null ?

Comment: Your `console.log` is in the error function, so that means there is an issue somewhere if you're seeing that. Check the console for errors, and also find out what the exact responseText of the request is

Comment: Before that I was using console.log(data) to display inside the success and it was outputting the correct data so yeah its not empty

Comment: I think you have problem with quote inside .html(). try this: $("#content_split").html("<div class='content_Reports'><p>Reporter<br/>"+data[i]['reporter']+"</p><br/></div>");

Comment: maybe `$("#content_split").append(<your html code>)`. if not, try editing the question adding the `php` part of the code

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with your jQuery selector. Are you sure there's an element with id `content_split`?

Also, you'll need to modify your success callback to this

```
  // ...
  success:function(data) {
          $("#content_split").html('');
          for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              $("#content_split").append("<div class='content_Reports><p>Reporter<br/>"+data[i]['reporter']+"</p><br/></div>'");
          }
      },
  //...
```

Comment: Nah it seems something else is in order, I tried to simply output Hello world and it works, must be something inside the HTML code itself

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by re-creating the HTML output itself, it had something to do with the original HTML code that I used, once I replaced it with the fresh typed one it worked. It have must been and ID problem or such